# Highlighting boundaries of certain shapes in a binary image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, blob, boundary

I have a task that requires analyzing an image filled with colored shapes and highlighting the blue circles in the image. To do this, I have split the image into its RGB channels and created a binary image of only the blue pixels. Using blob detection I've managed to segment the image and find the roundness for each of the shapes. However, when I try to place a boundary line on the round shapes, it places the boundary around ALL shapes, not just the circles. The relevant section of code is shown below;

```
imshow(BBinEro)
for cnt = 1:length(BlueProps)
    %disp(score);
    if score(cnt) >= 0.98 %
        text(BlueProps(cnt).Centroid(1),BlueProps(cnt).Centroid(2),num2str(score(cnt)),'color','red');

        boundaries = bwboundaries(BBinEro); 
        numberOfBoundaries = size(boundaries);
        hold on
        for k = 1 : numberOfBoundaries
            thisBoundary = boundaries{k};
            if score(cnt) >= 0.98 %Only showing for circles
            plot(thisBoundary(:,2), thisBoundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);
            end
        end
        hold off
    end    

end
```

"Score" is a measure of the circularity of the blob. A score of 1 means that the blob is perfectly round. The program displays the circularity of the round shapes at their centroid; using the same if-statement, I've attempted to incorporate inserting a boundary line around them. Any suggestions or observations on how I can fix this code so that it only shows the boundaries on the circles would be greatly appreciated.

The attached image shows what the program is currently doing. I want to get rid of the green boundaries around the triangle and the square.
[image]

Comment: You should be more specific as to what the variables in your code mean, and specially indicate which variables are specific to a single shape and which are vectors that refer to all shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to solve your problem:

```
[B,L,N,A] = bwboundaries(BBinEro);
for k=1:length(B)
    text(BlueProps(k).Centroid(1),BlueProps(k).Centroid(2),num2str(score(k)),'color','red');
    if(~sum(A(k,:))) & score(k) >= 0.98
        boundary = B{k};
        plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'r','LineWidth',2);
    end
end
```

I just added the condition `& score(k) >= 0.98` to an example in the matlab documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html). This assumes that the score array is ordered in the same way as the objects array generated by `bwboundaries`. If objects in `score` are ordered in the same way as the objects generated by `regionprops` then this is ok, since `regionprops` and `bwboundaries` index objects in the same order.

The error in your code lies in that you recalculate `bwboundaries(BBinEro)` with each iteration of your outer loop. Presumably you are trying to compute boundaries for each new object with each new iteration, but instead you are computing over the *entire* image (which I guess is `BBinEro`). Hope this solves your problem.